# Displaying a Video in an Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

What is the best way to display a video using VBA within an Excel Spreadsheet? I am currently thinking that the best way to do it will be to use Windows Media Player within a UserForm, but it seems like there is an easier way to do it. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far as I know, we cannot directly embed video file into Excel workbook. Here are some workaround to approach your goal:

**Method c.**

Convert the video into SWF format

```
Insert a Shockwave Flash Object control object from Developer > Controls > Insert > More Controls

Right click on it, and choose Properties, put the path to the SWF file in the Movie property and press Enter

Double click the EmbedMovie property to change its value as True

Click Design Mode button to exit design mode.

Save the workbook and share it.
```

**Method d.**

Embed the video into a PowerPoint presentation

```
Insert the presentaion in the workbook

Save the workbook and share it.
```

**Max Meng** April 27, 2012

Comment: Thanks Rafael, I am going to keep playing around to see if I can do exactly what I am trying to do, but it looks like your solution will work in the mean time!